# Itens repetidos com quantidades diferentes numa ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, android-adapter

Tenho uma Listview (*lsvProduto*) com alguns itens que vem de um request e um EditText de quantidade que o usuário pode alterar (como padrão, trago o valor de 0). Ao adicionar este item, eu mando ele pra outra ListView (*lsvCarrinho*) com uma estrutura bem parecida e com um EditText que tbm pode ser alterado, igual às imagens abaixo ():

[image: Produto]
[image: Carrinho]

**Problema**: Se eu adicionar um item na *lsvCarrinho* (2x ou mais) mas com quantidades diferentes, ao invés dele somar a quantidade de itens adicionados numa única linha, eu gostaria que ele deixasse em linhas separadas. Minha ListView já faz isso. No meu caso, se o mesmo item for adicionado mais de 1x, ele repete a última quantidade colocada (fica o item repetido mas com o valor de quantidade igual ao do último item que foi adicionado sendo que ele tinha sido adicionado com valor de quantidade diferente). O que eu faço pra ele diferenciar a quantidade mesmo se o item estiver sendo repetido seguidamente no listview? Ele não repete a quantidade, se eu adicionar um item diferente entre eles.

**Ex.:** Adicionei um Relógio - com quantidade igual a 2, depois adicionei o mesmo Relógio com quantidade igual a 3. Na minha ListView ficam 2 linhas com quantidade igual a 3. Aí se adiciono o mesmo Relógio com a quantidade igual a 5, na minha ListView ficam 3 linhas de Relógio com 5 na quantidade (Relógio = 5 / Relógio = 5 / Relógio = 5 mas deveria ficar Relógio = 2 / Relógio = 3 / Relógio = 5). Se eu colocar um Boné e depois um Relógio novamente fica assim (Relógio = 5 / Relógio = 5 / Relógio = 5 / Boné = 1 / Relógio = 1)

Código do adapter do Carrinho:

```
public class LancarVendaCarrinhoListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno> mDataSource;

public LancarVendaCarrinhoListViewAdapter(Context context, List<PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno> items)
{
    mContext = context;
    mDataSource = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mDataSource.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mDataSource.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    try
    {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View sView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_lancarvenda_carrinho_list_view_item, parent, false);

        PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno sItem = (PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno) getItem(position);

        TextView descricao = (TextView)sView.findViewById(R.id.lancarvenda_carrinho_item_txtdescricao);
        descricao.setText(sItem.getDescricao());

        TextView preco = (TextView)sView.findViewById(R.id.lancarvenda_carrinho_item_txvpreco);
        preco.setText(Texto.FormatarValor(sItem.getPreco()));

        NumberPicker quantidade = (NumberPicker)sView.findViewById(R.id.lancarvenda_carrinho_item_etquantidade);
        quantidade.setValue((int)sItem.getQuantidade());

        return sView;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

public List<PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno> getItemList()
{
    return mDataSource;
}

public void setItemList(List<PesquisarProdutoObjetoRetorno> itemList)
{
    this.mDataSource = itemList;
}
```

}

Código que adiciona os itens à lista:

```
Button adicionar = (Button)sView.findViewById(R.id.lancarvenda_produto_item_btnadicionar);
        adicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                sAdaptador = (LancarVendaCarrinhoListViewAdapter)lsvCarrinho.getAdapter();
                sCarrinhoAuxiliar = sAdaptador.getItemList();

                LancarVendaProdutosFragment.sProdutos.getDadosProduto().setQuantidade(Double.valueOf(quantidade.displayTextView.getText().toString()));

                sCarrinhoAuxiliar.add(LancarVendaProdutosFragment.sProdutos.getDadosProduto());

                LancarVendaProdutosTabBarActivity sActivity = ((LancarVendaProdutosTabBarActivity)mContext);

                LancarVendaCarrinhoFragment sFragment =
                        (LancarVendaCarrinhoFragment)sActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(1);
                sFragment.CarregarDados();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Produto adicionado ao carrinho", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                View toastView = toast.getView();
                toastView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toast_message_style);
                toast.show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Nossa. Parei de entender lá na parte que diz: tenho uma ListView...

Comment: Rapaz, sem brincadeiras. Esta confuso.

Comment: eu editei, veja se consegue entender agora... pq pra mim que estou com o problema na mão não ficou confuso!

Comment: vc fala um erro no carregamento do mDataSource?

Comment: Esse problema é de lógica de programação, pelo que entendi.
Toda vez que você for inserir um item no arrayList do carrinho, tem que verificar se já não tem nenhum produto adicionado com o mesmo Id, por exemplo....

Comment: ele não tem id diferente, nenhum dado é diferente, a não ser a quantidade e às vezes a quantidade tbm pode ser igual!

Comment: Exatamente... Na hora de adicionar mais itens, você verifica se existe um item com ID igual...Se o item que estiver entrando tiver ID igual, então significa que você vai ter que somar a quantidade de itens que estão entrando à quantidade de itens que já existe, e não criar uma nova "linha" no arrayList de itens do carrinho.

Comment: Você pode usar um Map para facilitar, onde a chave seria o ID do produto e o objeto seria o produto em si. Você também pode usar um ArrayList, mas vai ter que varrê-lo por inteiro toda vez que adicionar um item no carrinho.